# Are there terms for composite words that do not follow a logical etymological pattern?

Tags: etymology, emotions

For instance, we have two patterns for terms to describe sexual atteaction, one of which intersects a pattern for terms to describe a deep fondness for.

Homosexual, heterosexual, and bisexual follow a pattern of {object of sexual attraction]+”-sexual”.

Necrophile and pedophile follow a similar pattern but replaces “-sexual” with “-phile”.

Then, we have bibliophile and technophile that follow a similar pattern but replaces {object of sexual attraction] with {object of attraction/fondness].

The first and third categories make etymological sense, whereas the second category is in disparity with historical definitions of the root words.  Is there a term for the first and third categories along the lines of “homo-etymological” or “etymological parity”, and a term for the second group along the lines of “herero-etymological” or “etymological disparity”?

Is there a term that describes a word that takes the logical definition of another word that may or may not exist?  For example:  pedophile taking the definition for the word that should mean “a fondness for children.”

Is there a term for the process of bringing terms to etymological parity?

Ultimately, conflation and imprecise language has resulted in imprecise conversations regarding pedophiles.  Three demographics are affected by the “mis-coining” of one word, and the conflation of another.  Demographic one:  one who has a fondness for children should have been termed pedophiles.  Demographic two:  one who is sexually attracted to children should have been termed “pedosexuals.”  Demographic three:  one who has sexually molested a child is a “child molester.”  In many discussions, pedophile (which should have been pedosexual) has been conflated with child molesters.  Many fail to realize that pedophilism is an abnormal state of mind, whereas child molestation is the act of a horrendous crime.  Very few make that distinction which creates an unnecessarily hostile environment for the disturbed who have not yet acted.

Comment: This question is based on a false surmise. Both examples given do follow logical etymological principles. _-phile_ isn't necessarily sexual love, see [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-phile#etymonline_v_14852). It encompasses attraction (i.e. hygrophile, a chemical that mixes with - is attracted to - water), and is sometimes the opposite to a phobia. Greeks had lots of different words for love, and a _philos_ is a friendly love rather than sexual (which is _eros_).

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the term 'pedophile' was introduced at a time when there were open proponents of 'pedophilia'.  The term then in use was 'paederasty'.  This meant the erotic attraction to minors.  The replacement, 'pedophilia' was advanced as a kind of euphemism.  I remember disapproving at the time of the way in which the euphemism was taken up.  However, it is a euphemism no longer.  And nobody has thought of speaking of 'gynaecophilia' or 'androphilia'1

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the term 'pedophile' was introduced at a time when there were open proponents of 'pedophilia'.  The term then in use was 'paederasty'.  This meant the erotic attraction to minors.  The replacement, 'pedophilia' was advanced as a kind of euphemism.  I remember disapproving at the time of the way in which the euphemism was taken up.  However, it is a euphemism no longer.  And nobody has thought of speaking of 'gynaecophilia' or 'androphilia'.  In fact, there are many compound nouns in English, which you never notice: raincoat; sunshine; rainfall; nightmare ...

Comment: While it’s true that _paedophile_ should not necessarily be equated with _child molester_, that doesn’t make the word _paedophile_ unetymological in any way. There is a difference between _-sexual_ and _-phile_: the former describes the (mostly sex- or gender-related) directionality inherent in one’s sexual attractions; the latter describes particular ‘areas of interest’ _within_ that directionality. Sexualities are generally mutually exclusives; philias are not. You can be both a paedophile and a gerontophile at once, but you cannot be both homo- and heterosexual at once.

Comment: Also, why do you bracket words in that oddly {mixed way]?

Comment: The term for this kind of inconsistency is "English".

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: “you cannot be homo- and heterosexual at once.”  “Bisexual.”  The euphemism explanation makes the most sense whereas adding “sexual attraction” to -phila which was already distinct from -eros makes no etymological sense.

Comment: @marcellothearcane:  that is the point of the question.  Until recently (300 or so years) -phile meant fondness/adoration/attraction (non-sexual).  Adding “sexual attraction” to its meaning makes the language less precise and adds an element of arbitrariness.  What is the term for “adores children” or “enjoys working with cadavers”?

Comment: @tuffy "erotic attraction to minors" lol, it's quite literally "child molester".

Comment: @Digcoal No, being bisexual is not being homo- and heterosexual at once. Homo- and heterosexuality is being _exclusively_ attracted to the same and the opposite sex (or gender), respectively; bisexuality is (traditionally) being attracted to both or (more recently) being attracted to both your opposite sex/gender and any other (in which sense it overlaps a lot with pansexuality).

Comment: @vectory Absolutely incorrect.  An attraction, in regards to emotion, is a state of MIND.  Child molestation is an ACT.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Do you assert that a bisexual cannot have a homosexual desire or a heterosexual desire?

Comment: @Digcoal I would assert that a desire cannot have a sexuality at all. Desires and couples can be same-sex, opposite-sex or a variety of other things. Sexuality is a characteristic of living beings, not of thought, desires, couplings, marriages, etc. Someone who’s bisexual can be attracted to someone of the same sex/gender; that doesn’t make them homosexual.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  So “homosexual” cannot modify “desire” as an adjective?

Comment: @Digcoal I would say that it _shouldn’t_. There are of course many people who do use these terms like that (and in many other ways that aren’t ideal), but it’s not a usage most LGBT+ agree with, at least not in serious use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97645/discussion-between-digcoal-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Comment: “Sexual” is an adjective.  I do not see a problem with any derivations of that also being used as an adjective.  Certainly much less so than the bastardization of “-phile” as outlined in my question.

Comment: 'Is there a term for the process of bringing terms to etymological parity?' _Fantasy_?

Answer (score 0):

The original question was about the rules/patterns involved in the formation of composite words, rather than the particular words in the examples.

The answer is that all the words cited in the question are derived from ancient or mediaeval Greek or Latin.

Some words derived in this way are imported directly from the source languages, where the corresponding composites already existed.  *Geometry* is an example.  Here the *compository* rule was the use of the letter ‘o’.  Greek has two ‘o’s -  ‘omicron’, the same as the ‘o’ of most European languages, and the ‘omega’, a longer vowel sound, more like the word *awe* in classical times, though school kids of my generation were taught to pronounce it like ‘oh dear’.  It comes from *γη* (land where the η is a lengthened ‘e’ as in ‘air’, but today as in ‘eat’) and *μετρια* (measurement). So the Greeks shortened the ‘e’ and added an omega. Latin adopted the word lock, stock and barrel.  English does the same but replaces the final ‘ia’ with ‘y’.  French replaces ‘ia’ with ‘ie’ (*géométrie*), while Italian is the same as the Latin.

Later, European scientists, lawyers, doctors and scholars began to make up their own composites, based on paired GrecoRoman words, first because they were writing in Latin (as did Newton or Leibniz - who coined our word ‘calculus’), and later coining new compounds into English, German, French or other European languages, as appropriate.  In doing so, they followed the patterns already established in the ancient languages.

Some such patterns have shifted.   So what was spelled *paedo* has tended to lose the ‘a’ and become ‘pedo-‘.  A pedometer is an instrument for measuring children but measuring pedestrian speed.  And ‘a pedophile’ is certainly not someone with an erotic attraction to feet, though I believe such people do exist.  This is unfortunate, but the way of evolution,  now that knowledge of ancient languages is ebbing away and no longer controls the publication of language.

However, The question itself omits the vast teutonic fields of English, which allows words to fuse together without any alphabetic glue.  *sunshine*, *doorstep*, *makeup*, *bookend*.   Germanic English is really democratic.  We can invent new ideas without old codgers like me scoffing at our mistakes with the Greek and Latin we were never taught at school!

Comment: The original question is already supposing the existence of established meanings “imported directly from the source languages” and that some composite words follow the original meanings, and some words utilize “coined” meanings.  The question is asking if there are terms associated with the disparity between words that follow an original pattern and words that follow a newly established pattern.  Think in regards to teaching somebody latin/greek roots, then they come across words that do not follow that original teaching.

Comment: It’s a joke now, but in my younger years, I did not understand the animosity towards people whom like feet:  pedo- + -phile.  Obviously I made some incorrect assessments back then.  Pedo- I confused with Pod-, but phile didn’t just mean “attracted to” or “adores.”

Comment: @Digcoal Hence, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, the original word for sexual attraction to minors was not ‘pedophilia’ but the more explicit ‘paederasty’. with the correct spelling for the Greek word for slave, but no ‘o’ because the Greek word for erotic love begins with the vowel ‘e’.

Comment: Yes.  The question is “Is there a term for the disparity?”

Comment: @Digcoal I am sorry not to have realised quite what you were looking for.  In fact there is a misconception in your question.  The syllable ‘phile’ comes from the Greek word ‘philos’, meaning ‘friend’. ‘Philia’ is the kind of love you have for a friend. The word for romantic/erotic love (little distinction is made between the two kinds of love in ancient literature) is eros (as in ‘erotic’).  Hence the word for sexual attraction to minors was ‘paederasty’ (and one so attracted a ‘paederast’. [CONTINUED]

Comment: @Digcoal The oddest one out is ‘homosexuality’.  Had anyone been looking to be consistent, they would not have mixed the Greek word for ‘same’ (as in ‘homonym’ and ‘homophone’) and fused it to the mediaeval Latin-derived ‘sexual’.  It should have been ‘homoerasty’:  as in  ‘homoerotic’.  Moreover, there is a widespread belief that the Greek for ‘same’ (‘homoios’) is the Latin for ‘man’, ‘homo’, which in fact means ‘person’ so that the slur ‘homo’ is mistakenly used to refer to males only.   In other words, as with English spelling, follows certain principles ... but not consistently.

Comment: The most salient points thus far, and I appreciate them.  However, the inconsistency of pulling from two different languages is not as (or even at all) inconsistent as completely altering the meaning of the borrowed word.  The root -sexual has an already easily apparent definition in regards to that particular type of attraction.  Adding -phile to that definition muddies the conveyance for “sexual attraction” already accommodated by -sexual, as well as muddies the definition “friendly/plutonic/non-sexual attraction” that -phile had already accommodated.

Comment: @Digcoal Frankly, I was trying to get away from sex to language itself.  The ancients do not seem to have worried too much about who did what with whom.  The word ‘sex’ comes from the Latin ‘secus’, which means ‘apart’ and came to stand for what tells creatures apart: their sex —> gender.  Other words were used for what the two genders or same genders did in bed:  sex wasn’t one of them.   Remember that the innocent ‘phile’ becomes sinister by replacing ‘e’ with ‘iac’.  Paedophile was thought up to justify child abuse.

Comment: I would say that -sex was used to denote reproduction first, then the biological differences pertaining to that reproduction, then a more broadly used definition pertaining to the act of coitus separate from the purpose for it.  Other words that were coined all have a basis in the act of reproduction; even all the descriptions of psychological dysfunction of associations between reproduction and the objects with which to reproduce.  If “-sex” was coined incorrectly to denote a type of reproduction, that still does not excuse conflation with a second term.